# BTA12 triac driver circuit

Tags: triac

[image: schematic]

I'm using the circuit in the picture as a replacement for a mechanical relay running a 40 W, 220 V water pump.

The problem is that although the circuit seems to be correct, it doesn't work, and I'm getting a weird result on the multimeter.

When monitoring the AC output of the circuit with a multimeter, it shows 220 V when the logic input of the moc3042m is low. Also, this voltage doesn't turn on the pump. When changing the logic input to high (5 V), the output doesn't change.

- The actual pump is connected to the `J4` terminal.
- The `Pump` label in the picture is for the logic input.

If you see any problem in the schematic, please explain it.

Comment: Are you measuring the voltage with pump and multimeter connected to J4 in parallel, or only multimeter? BTW: D5 is not needed here.

Comment: Have you tried using a lamp as the load?

Comment: The circuit appears correct. The 220VAC multimeter measurement when 'off' is expected with the pump not connected because of the snubber network R3/C7. Carefully measure the voltage from pin 1 to 2 of U5 with the logic input high. It should be approximately 1.2VDC. You don't need VAC for the measurement.

Comment: @VillageTech i tried both and read around 220v, no difference.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes it is 1.235 vdc.

Comment: Try shorting 4 to 6 on U5 and see if the triac turns on. If there's something wrong R9 might burn up so be careful of that, and potential shock. If it does, then your wiring may be wrong or U5 may be bad.

Comment: @Andyaka When logic pin is low with lamp and multimeter connected in parallel to J4 terminal it cause the lamp to blink as fast as it is visible to human eye, like turn it on and of with a mechanical switch and multimeter read around 37 vac.
When logic pin becume high the lamp turn on constantly (i think the blink of it may not be visible to human eye ) and multimeter read around 220 vac and a gane at low logic level the lamp blink.

Comment: Was it an LED lamp? If so, that sounds normal because the snubber lets thru enough current.

Comment: Update : there is another bta12 driver circuit in board exactly like this one but without snubber circuit (it is for heater).
this one seems to work correctly with lamp and pump but only problem is when turn it off, a very small spark with a very small sound happen between triac (bta12) pin number 1 and 2, and also i think very few times when turn lamp off after a very short time (miliseconds) lamp does a blink. and also it works with pump but what is that spark for ? and can snubber circuit in the other circuit be the cause of problem ?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes it was an led lamp

Comment: @Andyaka and yes with other circuit without snubber it didn't blink.

Comment: Update: the problem seems to be the snubber circuit, without it every thing is working correctly. the only question is : when triac is off is it normal to measure around 17 volt ac at its output terminal with and without load connected ? and will absence of snubber circuit cause problem ?

Comment: Sounds normal. Test with an incandecent bulb as load in parallel to your multimeter.

Answer (score -1):

My opinion the circcuit is not that good.first if I were you I will try to connect pump before triac,Bta12 most efficient when 1 pin on negative rail.Moc 3041 is not ttl logic component it simple opto coupling  ( led-diac) if the dropping voltage in between leg 1 and 2 is not enough for driving of led then diac will not work.My guess is your moc is not working propely.But again I would not use this circuit.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is Kind of answering late (AFTER ALMOST 3 YEARS) :D But I think this circuit is absolutely not correct. you see, the pump connected parallel to triac and this Cause the pump to be turn on even without "DRIVE PULSE" to its gate. so first of all connect the pump serial between the triac and AC supply voltage.
Then, What is R8???? I mean, what was the purpose? if its a gate driver it must connect serial between second pin of secondary part of optotriac and the gate. finally connect pin 1 of triac to second pin of AC supply. tnx by :)

Comment: Did you mean "snubber"? The "pump" connector is clearly in series...

Comment: khalil seidali - Hi, A different account tried to make a major edit to your answer. If that was you, then please use the same account to do the edit as you used to write this answer. Otherwise we don't know that it is you and such a major edit should only be done by an answer's original author. If you want to delete your answer then you can do that, again using the original account. (On desktop browsers, you will see a "Delete" link below the answer. If you cannot see that, you can flag your answer and ask a moderator to delete it but, again, only from the original account.) Thanks.